# Extruding along vertex normals gives weird result

Tags: normals, extrude, error

I know I'm probably making some silly mistake after hours of consecutive work.

I have a cylinder representing a gun barrel, and at one point I want to add a 'ring' around the barrel, as shown below.

[image]

At the point shown, I added an edge loop, beveled it with hopes of extruding it along the normals, however I'm getting weird behavior.

[image]
[image]

The faces refuse to extrude outward, and will only go sideways like the second image. Here's my interface too, which I scanned for mismatched settings but can find none.

[image]

Can you see what's wrong? I checked for duplicate geometry, found 0 double vertices and I tried doing it with a new primitive cylinder, and it works like a wonder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say where you've messed up, anyway, here is what you should do, if I've correctly understood what you try to do (?):

- Create your edge loop at the middle of your cylinder with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>.
- Bevel it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude then <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away.
- Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale your extrude, and <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> (or <kbd>Y</kbd> depending on the orientation) to constraint your extrude on both Y and Z axis.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I was so absorbed with the vertex normals that I didn't even try the simple solution.